# How to group data weekly in column and hourly in row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like following

```
ID  SalesTime           Qty Unit Price Item 
1   01/01/2021 08:10:00 10       10    A
2   01/01/2021 11:30:00  2        9    B
3   01/01/2021 11:59:50  1        8    C
4   01/02/2021 13:00:00  5       15    D
5   01/03/2021 10:00:00  4       10    A 
6   01/03/2021 12:00:00  5        9    B
7   01/03/2021 12:50:00  6       15    D
8   01/04/2021 10:50:00  5        8    C
9   01/04/2021 11:10:00  2       10    A
10 ............
```

I wanna summarize the total into the form,
for example:

```
              Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
08:00~09:59    20  21  50 100  60  70 210 
10:00~11:59    60  25  60  90  75  80 200  
12:00~13:59   100  10  50  60  70  50 150
```

How to do that in MS SQL, thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to total?

Comment: qty * unit_price as you answered

Comment: is the value of mon column's first row sum(qty* unitprice) of all the rows between 8.00 to 9.59 in all mondays within the date range?

Comment: yes, not only Monday, each weekday does the same thing to summarize bihourly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the hour and divide by two for the rows.  And then use conditional aggregation for the columns.  Assuming you want the total of the price times quantity:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(hour, 2 * (datepart(hour, salestime) / 2), 0)) as hh,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, salestime) = 'Monday' then qty * unit_price end) as mon,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, salestime) = 'Tuesday' then qty * unit_price end) as tue,
       . . . 
from t
group by datepart(hour, salestime) / 2
order by min(salestime);
```

Note:  This just returns the beginning of the time period, rather than the full range.